# Where put subroutine/function to inline

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

If I want a subroutine to be inlined in the calling routine, where may I keep it? Need it be in the same module or file? Can inlining be done with subroutines from different object files? May the answer be compiler dependent?

Comment: For a more or less compiler independent result, use internal procedures (CONTAINS).  ifort with default setting -Qip inlines (partially?) automatically from all source files given in a single compile command, subject to the inline limits settings.

Comment: @tim18 Putting it in the contains statement is inconvenient for reuse, and because of the overlapping name spaces. Putting a module with small routines in the same compile statement as the caller seems clean. Then the module can be reused and if the calling becomes time consuming for a caller, one can put it on same line as the caller in the make file. I wonder if this works for gfortran, which is the compiler I usually use?

Answer (score 2):

This is not controlled by the Fortran standard. The processor can do as it sees fit.

It will definitely depend on the compiler settings.

Commonly, internal functions will be inlined. But many other other functions are often inlined as well, at least if they happen to be in the same source file or module.

But even inlining from other source files / compiled object files is not out of the question. That can and is often done during link time optimizations (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization). These optimizations are either included in certain compiler flags (like `-fast`) or can be enabled separately (`-flto`,`-ipo`).

Comment: And by internal functions you mean those in a `contains` statement of the caller? It would be nice to be able to have a module in a separate file with commonly used small routines like cross product, dot product, some elemental function etc., and be able to assume they will be inlined. Maybe it helps if such module is compiled in the same statement as the routine using it, like `gfortran $(flags) caller.f90 utils.f90` where utils.f90 contains the module with the small routines?

Comment: *Internal procedures* is an exactly defined term. They are in the contains section of the main program or another procedure (typically the caller). For your flags try using `-flto` and see what the compiler manages to inline. The result will dependd on the size of the funcion to be inlined.

Comment: How do you determine whether the inlining was successful? I'm on Ubuntu with gfortran. I've just been using `gprof` or `perf` for profiling.